# find something gone or find something has gone

Tags: meaning, word-usage, sentence

Are both of them right?

1. *Next morning when you wake up, you find your kidney has gone.*
2. *Next morning when you wake up, you find your kidney gone.*

If they are all right, what's the difference?

Comment: Yes, they're both correct, but they come from different structures. (1) deletes the _that_ complementizer of a tensed complement of _find_ -- _you find **that** your kidney has gone_. (2) deletes the _to be_ of an infinitive complement (with [B-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf)) of _find_ -- _you find your kidney **to be** gone_. _Find_ can take [both types of complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Complements.pdf).

Comment: Since 'find that' echoes 'find out that', I think that the the former is more appropriate here. It's probably not the first thing you're going to notice, as in finding your furniture gone.

Comment: If you "find your kidney has gone", it sounds like it left on its own accord.  If you kidney is missing (and hasn't grown legs), than you'd say you "found it gone".

Comment: @Edwin: As John says, OP's two different versions reflect two different underlying structures. And for me at least, whereas *find* works fine with both, alternatives such as *discover, detect* are decidedly "iffy" for the second. And I'd class *find **out*** as right up there with something like *realise* - it really doesn't work in the second construction.

Comment: @Kristina: Sorry to rain on your parade, but I don't think any such distinction would occur to most native speakers.

Comment: Rain away, @FumbleFingers, to my eye and ear, "my kidney has gone" sounds strange and slightly suspicious. :-)

Comment: @FF In 'They entered the office and found the computer destroyed', arguably the original was 'They entered the office and found the computer in a destroyed state'. There's still a hint of coming across the thing ('They entered the office and found the computer. It was totally destroyed.') 'Found X missing' has this nuance, which sounds incongruous.

Comment: @Kristina: To my eye and ear (and brain! :) the idea that you might wake up to discover one of your internal organs isn't there any more sounds a lot worse than "suspicious". Apart from anything else, how would you *know* one of your kidneys was missing? You can get by fine with just the other one, and I'm sure millions of people are blissfully aware they are in fact doing this ([1 in 2400 are apparently born with only one functioning kidney](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicystic_dysplastic_kidney)), and I bet most of them never ***find the other one non-functional*** at all).

Comment: @Edwin: No. As John says, the underlying construction there is "subjunctive" *found the computer **to be** destroyed*. In that *specific* utterance I have to say explicitly including the missing verb sounds a bit weird to me, but I'm happier with it where *find* carries more the sense of *classified, decided, adjudged*, as in *"I've tried various folk remedies, but found them to be ineffective"*.

Comment: @FF I'm not sure how one can decide precedents. Perhaps there's a lot of investigative work one (eg me) is unaware of. Here, though, I could compare with the depictive construction 'We saw that the soldier had been shot. It was too dangerous to bury the poor guy; _we left him dead in the road_.

Comment: @Edwin: I don't know. I'm just "working outwards" from what John said first off, which would seem unassailable to me even if I didn't take it for granted he knows much more about such matters than most of us. That's to say, I'm convinced OP's #2 "derives" from an infinitive complement - with *to be* deleted, but it still sounds fine if you add that back. But I can't say the same about *"We left him **to be** dead in the road"*, and I can't see exactly why *"We left him **to be** standing there"* sounds even worse, even though it looks like a similar construction.

Comment: I think the choice of 'kidney' hasn't helped here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the phrase could be said by a hospitalised patient who has donated his organ, a kidney, to another. You "wake up" from the anaesthesia/after the operation finding your kidney gone.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Disregarding judges in trials etc., the general rule is when you "find" something, it's ***unexpected***. It's hard to see how someone could unexpectedly nick your kidney, even if you *were* asleep/anaesthetized at the time.

Comment: Metaphorically speaking, @FumbleFingers , use your imagination. It could be said by the donor, ironically, as a means to lessen the drama/trauma. Yes, of course the donor knew about the operation, but he could be talking about it in a nonchalantly manner. *It's possible but... unlikely*! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is, intentionally or not, a slightly comical element discernible in the notion of "finding something gone," in much the same way as when Alice tells the King of Hearts that she sees nobody on the road, and he responds (fretfully),

> "I only wish I had such eyes. To be able to see Nobody! And at that distance, too! Why it's as much as I can do to see real people, by this light!"

One lyricist who exploited the comic possibility of "found gone" is Michael Flanders, in his song "[Ill Wind](http://www.classicalmusicguide.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=14126)" (set to the tune of the rondo in *Mozart's Horn Concerto No. 4 in E-Flat Major*), which tells the cautionary tale of a man who mysteriously loses his French horn after a day during which he spent hours attempting to learn to play it. He describes the discovery of the disappearance thus:

> Who swiped that horn?
>   I bet you a quid somebody did.
>   Knowing I found a concerto,
>   And wanted to play it,
>   Afraid of my talent at playing the horn.
>   For early today to my utter dismay,
>   It had vanished away like the dew in the morn.
>   I've lost that horn!
>   I know I was using it yesterday.
>   I've lost that horn, lost that horn,
>   Found that horn gone.

Idiomatically, of course, people "find [things] gone" all the time, but if you want to avoid even the possibility that someone will respond to your revelation about your lost kidney by asking jocularly "How could you find it if it's still missing?" you might want to frame your wording as "Just this morning, I found that one of my kidneys is [or has] gone."

Comment: Yep; I beg to concur.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the underlying sense of ***find*** here. It doesn't *directly* refer to finding the kidney (or not, as the case may be). It's about finding/discovering ***the fact that*** the kidney is present/missing.

Comment: It's an intentional misunderstanding by the would-be jokester. For some reason, I think of the wordplay in Beyond the Fringe's "Royal Box," where one of the attendees of the play cites "the royal prerogative" to sit in the Royal Box, and a bit later, remarking on how much younger the Duchess of Glastonbury looks than she actually is, Dudley (I think) says "It must be an example of the royal preservative!" To which Peter (I think) asks, "What is that—some sort of cream?" And Dudley replies, "No—it's a joke."

Comment: Or maybe the "royal prerogative" had to do with the Queen's instruction to the Royal Bengal Crouchers that they keep their crouch-inducing accoutrements of ceremonial medals and ceremonial garters...I don't remember which one it was.

Answer (score -2):

If you change `'you find'` to what it actually means in this context - `'you discover that`' then it should be clear which one is more correct, but the second one still conveys the meaning perfectly in speech and is possibly more dramatic if you can slip in a pause between `'kidney'` and `'gone'`.

But John's comment explains why in much more detail than I could.

Comment: This is completely wrong, in that it uses comparison with a "near-synonymous" alternative verb to justify the false assertion that only one of OP's constructions is "correct". Per my own comment to the question, it just so happens that *find* allows the "elided subjunctive" form, whereas most other similar words don't. You can't extrrapolate valid usages for *find* by considering valid usages for *discover*.

Comment: Hmmm, food for thought there.

Comment: Don't think too much about my "elided subjunctive" there (I make no claim to understand the correct terminology). All I'm really saying is that some words (particularly, I think, verbs relating to *perception, emotion, knowledge,* etc.) can be used in certain grammatical constructions where other words can't. Even though those alternative words might be very close synonyms which can directly replace the original word in *other* constructions. Essentially, the "grammar" of any given word doesn't necessarily conform to the grammar of all (or *any*) closely-related words.

Comment: Next morning when you wake up, you find your issue clarified somewhat. I must have used the second form at some point in my life in speech "when I woke up, I found my wallet empty" but I cannot imagine using the second form in writing. When reporting it to the authorities I would feel compelled to write "When I woke up, I found my wallet to be empty".  To me, the first sentence is more correct simply because it is clear in both spoken and written forms, the second sentence I would only use in speech. In the matter of wrongful substitution of a verb, the defendant pleads 'guilty as charged'.